# Keyboard bind detection priority

Tags: python-3.x, keyboard, keylistener

I have created a script that listens to the keyboard if `keyboard.is_pressed(key)` and performs some action (now just typing text).
The program works, but for example when I use this in notepad (with alt+1 bind) sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.
Does anyone know of solutions to give the highest priority to my bind?
I want the combination to be `ctrl-left` or `alt-left`, which generates problems.

```
t_pressed = tde_pressed = teng_pressed = False
    last_activation_time = 0
    debounce_delay = 0.3  # 

    while should_continue:
        current_time = time.time()
        
        if Key_1_translate and Key_2_translate:
            if keyboard.is_pressed(Key_1) and keyboard.is_pressed(Key_2):
                if not t_pressed and current_time - last_activation_time > debounce_delay:
                    copy_and_print() #a function that does something
                    t_pressed = True
                    last_activation_time = current_time
            else:
                t_pressed = False
```

When the program is reset, it works properly again.
Most problems occur when the active window also uses function keys.

Comment: Please post complete & reproducible code.